# Build Error: Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:transform-api:1.5.+

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Starting to get an error while building project without any changes have happened by me in gradle. I'm suspicious that the some code has been deleted from jcenter or maven side.

Has any one encountered this problem? I'll appreciate any solution. Thanks

BUILD ERROR:

```
Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:transform-api:1.5.+.
Search in build.gradle files
```

root gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.17.2"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/visilabs/maven/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

// Load dependencies
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding :

```
    maven{
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'
    }
```

Comment: I've included the following and it worked thank you @Aykut Celik

Comment: HI can u explain why this is needed?.Ive had the same issue with exoplayer

Comment: Don't know exactly. Somehow they removed from other repositories.Probably it will be fixed soon.